# Numpy outer addition of subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting

Is there a way, in numpy, to perform what amounts to an outer addition of subarrays?

That is to say, I have 2 arrays of the form `2x2xNxM`, which may each be considered a stack of `2x2` matrices `N` high and `M` wide. I would like to add each of these matrices to each matrix from the other array, to form a `2x2xNxMxNxM` array in which the last four indices correspond to the indices in my initial two arrays so that I can index `output[:,:,x1,y1,x2,y2] == a1[:,:,x1,y1] + a2[:,:,x2,y2]`.

If these were arrays of scalars, it would be trivial, all I'd have to do is:

```
A, B = a.ravel(), b.ravel()
four_D = (a[...:np.newaxis] + b).reshape(*a1.shape, *a2.shape)

for (x1, y1, x2, y2), added in np.ndenumerate(four_D):
    assert added == a1[x1,y1] + a2[x2,y2]
```

However, this doesn't work for the case where `a` and `b` comprise of matrices. I could, of course, use nested for loops, but my dataset is going to be fairly large, and I'm expecting to run this over multiple datasets.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend arrays to have more dimensions and then leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
output = a1[...,None,None] + a2[...,None,None,:,:]
```

Sample run -

```
In [38]: # Setup input arrays
    ...: N = 3
    ...: M = 4
    ...: a1 = np.random.rand(2,2,N,M)
    ...: a2 = np.random.rand(2,2,N,M)
    ...: 
    ...: output = np.zeros((2,2,N,M,N,M))
    ...: for x1 in range(N):
    ...:     for x2 in range(N):
    ...:         for y1 in range(M):
    ...:             for y2 in range(M):
    ...:                 output[:,:,x1,y1,x2,y2] = a1[:,:,x1,y1] + a2[:,:,x2,y2]
    ...: 
    ...: output1 = a1[...,None,None] + a2[...,None,None,:,:]
    ...: 
    ...: print np.allclose(output, output1)
True
```

Comment: Well, dang. That turned out to be simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Same as for scalars inserting additional axes works for higher dimensional arrays too (this is called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)):

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.random.randn(2, 2, 3, 4)
a2 = np.random.randn(2, 2, 3, 4)
added = a1[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis] + a2[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, :]

print(added.shape)  # (2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4)
```

Comment: How is this any different from my solution? `None` is just np.newaxis for extending dimensions.

Comment: @Divakar It's the same, we posted practically simultaneously ;)

Comment: Well your initial solution was with np.add.outer which didn't work and that you edited within that 5 mins time period to this.

Comment: I really like your solutions, but this feels wrong to me :)

Comment: Yep, but that was not my solution - note that it would not have matched the output i posted along with it. This was a copy & paste mistake that I corrected (I tried `add.outer` too see if there were alternatives and copied the wrong line).